# Finding duplicate elements in a Scheme List

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm trying to become more familiar with recursion in Scheme. I have searched the question bank and see many "built-in" functions for finding duplicate entries in a scheme list, but am trying to design my own. I have not learned about "lambda" yet either. My concern is when I call the recursion function, the car element will be updated. I wish to keep it the same, but pass a new cdr each time, so the original car element can be compared against each subsequent element in the list. I want to return a #t if there is a match, and #f if there is no match or the cdr is empty (base case). Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
(define (findDuplicates list)
    (if (null? list)
       #f
       (if (null? (cdr list))
           #f
             (if (= (car list) (getCarOfCdr list)) 
              #t
              (findDuplicates (cdr list))    //trying to use recursion
             )
        )
    )
)


(define (getCarOfCdr list)          //Helper function
  (car (cdr list))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use at least one built-in procedure to make things simpler: [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29) (which is standard). Some general suggestions:

- You should not call a parameter `list`, that clashes with a built-in function with the same name.
- Don't nest `if`s like that, use `cond` instead.
- We only need two base cases for this problem, not three as in your code.
- `getCarOfCdr` is not necessary: it can be replaced by a call to `cadr` and besides, that won't work: you have to check each element against *all the rest of the list* - that's why you should use `member`.

Taking all of the above suggestions into consideration, here's my proposed solution:

```
(define (findDuplicates lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((member (car lst) (cdr lst)) #t)
        (else (findDuplicates (cdr lst)))))
```

If using `member` doesn't satisfy your requirements, then it's easy to implement, and  simpler than `findDuplicates`; you should try to write your own version, just for fun.